# Javascript how to sort a 2d array

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have a 2d array and I want to sort it

```
var result = {
   validationdate : [
      "2023-03",
      "2022-11",
      "2023-01",
      "2023-04"
   ],
   program : [
      "a",
      "a",
      "b",
      "a"
   ],
}
result.validationdate.sort()
return result
```

But I obtain this :

```
{
   "validationdate": [
      "2022-11",
      "2023-01",
      "2023-03",
      "2023-04"
   ],
   "program": [
      "a",
      "a",
      "b",
      "a"
   ]
}
```

How can I sort the program column like the validationdate sort and obtain :

```
{
   "validationdate": [
      "2022-11",
      "2023-01",
      "2023-03",
      "2023-04"
   ],
   "program": [
      "a",
      "b",
      "a",
      "a"
   ]
}
```

I notice that validationdate is a string column
Thanks in advance !

Comment: Its an object of array. You will have to sort them manually. Put this line: `result.program.sort()` as well

Comment: @Rajesh `program`'s sort will be according to `validationdate`'s sorting

Comment: You asked this 15 minutes before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you could do is create an array of indexes, and sort them based the associated date.

```
// ["2023-03","2022-11","2023-01","2023-04"]
const order = Array.from(result.validationdate.keys());
// [0,1,2,3]
order.sort((a, b) => result.validationdate[a].localeCompare(result.validationdate[b]));
// [1,2,0,3]
```

With the index order we can now replace the current values of `validationdate` and `program`, by mapping the index to its associated value.

```
result.validationdate = order.map(index => result.validationdate[index]);
result.program = order.map(index => result.program[index]);
```

```js
var result = {
  validationdate: ["2023-03","2022-11","2023-01","2023-04"],
  program: ["a","a","b","a"],
};

const order = Array.from(result.validationdate.keys());
// [0,1,2,3]
order.sort((a, b) => result.validationdate[a].localeCompare(result.validationdate[b]));
// [1,2,0,3]

result.validationdate = order.map(index => result.validationdate[index]);
result.program = order.map(index => result.program[index]);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve in this way:

1. Create a orderList that holds key-value pair of validation date and program
2. Then sort `validationdate`
3. Then loop on sorted array and fetched mapped values from orderList. Assign it to `result.program`

```js
function getSortedValue() {
  var result = {
    validationdate: ["2023-03", "2022-11", "2023-01", "2023-04"],
    program: ["a", "a", "b", "a"],
  }
  const order = result.validationdate.reduce(
    (acc, item, index) => ({...acc, [item]: result.program[index] }),
    {}
  )
  result.validationdate.sort()
  result.program = result.validationdate.map((item) => order[item])
  return result
}

console.log(getSortedValue())
```

Answer (score 1):

To sort the `program` array based on the sorted `validationdate` array, we can create an array of objects that contains the values from both arrays. Then we can sort this array based on the `validationdate` property, and extract the sorted program array from the sorted array of objects.

```js
const result = {
  validationdate: ["2023-03", "2022-11", "2023-01", "2023-04"],
  program: ["a", "a", "b", "a"],
};

// create an array of objects with corresponding values
let array = result.validationdate.map(function(value, index) {
  return {
    validationdate: value,
    program: result.program[index],
  };
});

// sort the array based on validationdate
array.sort(function(a, b) {
  return new Date(a.validationdate) - new Date(b.validationdate);
});

// extract/split the sorted array
let sortedArrays = {
  program: [],
  validationdate: []
};

array.map(function(value) {
  sortedArrays.program.push(value.program);
  sortedArrays.validationdate.push(value.validationdate);
});

// log
console.log(sortedArrays);
```

Comment: The final `array.map()` call should be a `forEach()`, since you don't use the return value of `map()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
let temp1 = result.validationdate.map((item,index)=>({date:item,program: result.program[index]}));
temp1.sort((a,b)=>new Date(a.date)-new Date(b.date))
```

Output :- [
{
"date": "2022-11",
"program": "a"
},
{
"date": "2023-01",
"program": "b"
},
{
"date": "2023-03",
"program": "a"
},
{
"date": "2023-04",
"program": "a"
}
]
then only we want to form our object again